# laravel moving to production broke my application

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, laravel-5

I have moved my laravel5 app to aws ec2, but when the redirects happens it goes to localhost instead of being there on production site. I know this must be very easy fix but I have been searching through their documentation but didn't find anything useful so far.

my app.php -

```
'url' => 'http://ec2-54-200-173-76.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com',
```

my env file -

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=ec2-54-200-173-76.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

But when I load the index page after login it redirects to my localhost's home page instead of production site's home page.

Comment: I take it you've already tried clearing your cache?

Comment: @vascowhite Hey, I am still getting error for route not found on apache2 however it is there in laravel

Comment: have you given permissions to route file?

Comment: well funny thing is baseurl/index.php/home works but baseurl/home doesn't

Comment: it's your .htaccess problem

Comment: May this URL will help you: https://hellocoding.wordpress.com/2014/05/17/how-to-remove-public-from-url-in-laravel/

Comment: Thanks Waqas got that fixed as Apache was not allowing override